# Switch statement inside Razor CSHTML

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm developing a project in ASP.NET MVC4, Twitter.Bootstap 3.0.0 and Razor. In a View, I need to display buttons depending of a property value. Using the `switch` statement, the example below doesn't work (nothing is displayed):

```
@switch (Model.CurrentStage) { 
    case Enums.Stage.ReadyToStart:
        Html.ActionLink(Language.Start, "Start", new { id=Model.ProcessId }, new { @class = "btn btn-success" });
        break;
    case Enums.Stage.Flour:
        Html.ActionLink(Language.GoToFlour, "Details", "Flours", new { id=Model.Flour.FlourId }, new { @class = "btn btn-success" });
        break;
    ...
}
```

Changing a bit, using a `<span>` tag, the code works:

```
@switch (Model.CurrentStage) { 
    case Enums.Stage.ReadyToStart:
        <span>@Html.ActionLink(Language.Start, "Start", new { id=Model.ProcessId }, new { @class = "btn btn-success" })</span>
        break;
    case Enums.Stage.Flour:
        <span>@Html.ActionLink(Language.GoToFlour, "Details", "Flours", new { id=Model.Flour.FlourId }, new { @class = "btn btn-success" })</span>
        break;
    ...
}
```

Can someone explain why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's the funkiness of Razor. When you're in normal HTML and use C# code, putting something with an `@` symbol on it will write the result to the page:

```
<p>@Html.ActionLink("whatever", "whatever"...)</p>
```

This is similar to the old-school `<%= %>`.

```
<p><%= SomeMethodThatReturnsSomethingThatWillBeWritten() %></p>
```

However, the Html.ActionLink method simply returns an `MvcHtmlString` object in the .NET world. In your first example, you've got a regular C# code block. So calling `Html.ActionLink()` from there simply executes it and returns the `MvcHtmlString` to nobody. In your second example, you've jumped back into the HTML context, so it writes the HTML again.

You can use the special `<text>` block to get back to HTML instead of using `<span>` or other real HTML, and it will write directly without writing the extra HTML:

```
case Enums.Stage.ReadyToStart:
    <text>@Html.ActionLink(Language.Start, "Start", new { id=Model.ProcessId }, new { @class = "btn btn-success" })</text>
    break;
```

You can also use the similar `@:` syntax:

```
case Enums.Stage.ReadyToStart:
    @:@Html.ActionLink(Language.Start, "Start", new { id=Model.ProcessId }, new { @class = "btn btn-success" })
    break;
```

You can read more about both [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/15/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax.aspx)

**EDIT**

Actually, in this case, you don't need either one. You just need the `@` symbol, which will be enough to get you back into the HTML:

```
case Enums.Stage.ReadyToStart:
    @Html.ActionLink(Language.Start, "Start", new { id=Model.ProcessId }, new { @class = "btn btn-success" })
    break;
```

Comment: I liked most of the last example. Thanks!

Comment: I never knew about the @: syntax. Very helpful!